# Trying to use button to set a value on $scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use this code below to set a value on $scope when a button is touched. It doesn't seem to be working - how should I go about it? I googled a lot of other questions concerning buttons but they are not quite this specific issue.

```
<input type="button" value="Not Important" ng-click="setImportance(1)">
<input type="button" value="Important" ng-click="setImportance(2)">
<input type="button" value="Extremely" ng-click="setImportance(3)">


$scope.setImportance = function (value){
    if (Number(value) == 1){
        $scope.question.importance = "notImportant";
        console.log("$scope.question.importance: " + $scope.question.importance)
    } else if (Number(value) == 2){
        $scope.question.importance = "important";
        console.log("$scope.question.importance: " + $scope.question.importance)
    } else if (Number(value) == 3){
        $scope.question.importance = "veryImportant";
        console.log("$scope.question.importance: " + $scope.question.importance)
    }
    console.log(Number(value));
    console.log("importance is: " + $scope.question.importance)
}
```

Comment: what is `Number(value)` in your function?

Comment: Are any of the console.log statements inside your if/else branches being hit? As @pankajparkar alluded perhaps Number(value) is not returning an expression that is matched by any of them

Comment: Number(value) takes the string version of the input and makes it a number. I tried this b/c it worked on an href ng-click that was having trouble with a string, and worked with that fix

The console.logs are being hit, and they are spitting out 'undefined'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not doing anything else with `value` it might be a lot easier for you to just set the value directly on the click instead of using an if/else.

```
<input type="button" value="Not Important" ng-click="question.importance = 'notImportant'">
<input type="button" value="Important"  ng-click="question.importance = 'important'">
<input type="button" value="Extremely"  ng-click="question.importance = 'veryImportant'">
```

Comment: @Femtosecond np :) feel free to mark as the answer if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in the contoller is like in the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/Lg1cLsrc/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    var mapping = {
            '1': 'Not important',
            '2': 'Important',
            '3': 'Very important'
        };
    $scope.question = {
        importance: ""
    };
    
    $scope.setImportance = function(value) {
        $scope.question.importance = mapping[value];
    };
    
    $scope.setImportance(1); //init default
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <input type="button" value="Not Important" ng-click="setImportance(1)"/>
    <input type="button" value="Important" ng-click="setImportance(2)"/>
    <input type="button" value="Extremely" ng-click="setImportance(3)"/>
    {{question.importance}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of other ways to achieve what are you trying to do. But it's nice to know what is wrong with the code at first.

You need to initialize the object first before accessing the property of that object. For your case specifically, you need to initialize `$scope.question` with empty object. Just to let the compiler know it is an object.

```
$scope.question = {};
```

When you are trying to do $scope.question.importance without initializing it, the interpreter will try to find question to check the property. But it can't find it since it is not defined.

Lets visualize this with a very basic figure.

[image]

After the $scope.question.importance is set with some value, it will looks like:

[image]
Also,note that you don't have to cast with `Number`. Both ways should work, it just unnecessary

. 
Then, it should works!

https://jsfiddle.net/rzg53u03/

Comment: Do you get this idea?